# Populating DataGrid: how to manipulate data before showing it on C# MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, visual-studio, datagrid

First of all, I'm new in the VS2015+C#+XAML, I came from VB6 so I'm use to do things in a way and I want to figure out how to do those same things in VS2015.

I need to populate a DataGrid in my WPF application from a MySQL database so I found that there are two ways to do so:

1) Manually by using:

```
DataGrid.Items.Add(MyCustomClass)
```

2) Filling it with

```
DataGrid.ItemsSource = DataTable.DefaultView;
```

I think that the best ways is using the second method, it´s faster and I don´t need to create a custom class for each resultset I want to display. It worked perfectly until I start trying to make some of the things I use to do in VB6

I save the dates in the Database as numbers not as dates for convenience, so when I retrieve the date I format it before showing it, same case with other types of data.

But when I do it in c# I can't manipulate data before showing it.

Main issues:

1) When trying to display a concatenated SQL field it shows byte[] Array instead of the actual data.

2) Can't manipulate the date before showing it.

My XAML code

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="oViewer" FontSize="26.667" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="10" Margin="20,0,0,0" Foreground="Black" Cursor="None"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0">
            <StackPanel Margin="10,10,10,10">
                <Button Content="Fill Data" Click="Button_Click"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Customers:"/>
                <DataGrid x:Name="G" Height="160" Margin="0,5,0,10" RowHeight="40" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Width="SizeToCells" Binding="{Binding CODE}" FontSize="11" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="SizeToCells" Binding="{Binding NAME}" FontSize="11" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Width="SizeToCells" Binding="{Binding EDATE,StringFormat=\{0:dd-MMM-yyyy\}}" FontSize="11" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>

                </DataGrid>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

As you can see I try something with the date, without achieving anything.

My C# Code

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        DB DB = new DB(); //MYSQL CONNECTION CLASS
        string SQL = "SELECT NAME, DATE, CONCAT(LETTER,NUMBER) AS CODE";
        DataTable RS = DB.Select(SQL); //DB.SELECT RETURN A DATATABLE WITH RESULT SET

        G.ItemsSource = RS.DefaultView; //POPULATING THE DATAGRID


    }
```

Hope you can give me a hand with this. Thanks in advance for your answer and time.

EDIT

Now I do this in order to have more control over the data type and the values.

```
MySqlDataReader LECTOR = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                /**********/ //RS.Load(LECTOR); //This is What I was using

                bool flag = true;

                while (LECTOR.Read()) {
                    if (flag) { //if first time then I create all the columns
                        for (int i = 0; i < LECTOR.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            //name of the column
                            RS.Columns.Add(LECTOR.GetName(i));
                            //change the datatype to String So I can manipulate the value later
                            RS.Columns[LECTOR.GetName(i)].DataType = typeof(string);
                        }

                        flag = !flag;

                        DataRow FILA = RS.NewRow();

                        for (int i = 0; i < LECTOR.FieldCount; i++)
                        {/***********************/
                            //I'm Failing here, I don't know how to cring that concat value, it keeps giving me datatype error like System.Byte[] or Byte[] Array
                         /***********************/

                            FILA[LECTOR.GetName(i)] = LECTOR.GetValue(i).ToString();

                        }
                        RS.Rows.Add(FILA);
                    }
                }
```

So what's the best approach here?, I'm reading MSDN forums and trying things without any result.

Comment: `I save the dates in the Database as numbers not as dates for convenience` - Doesn't really sound very "convenient"....

Comment: It is not generally convenient but it happen to be the best approach for this App. =)

Comment: clearly not. Modern development practices are much more convenient and "better" than traditional VB6 practices from 20 years ago. I recommend you read about Entity Framework, LINQ, MVVM and DataBinding.

Comment: Of course! you are right! but the application is alive and working perfectly, I[m working with another app on the same dataBase so I have to adapt to it, any way I don´t have problems just with the dates, there´s the Byte[] Array problem which came from concat SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to have full control I did this

```
MySqlDataReader LECTOR = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                bool flag = true;
                while (LECTOR.Read()) {
                    if (flag) { //first time it creates the columns
                        for (int i = 0; i < LECTOR.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            //creates the columns
                            RS.Columns.Add(LECTOR.GetName(i));
                            //Change the column (in this case I can use a conditional statement to be more specific and accurate about the data type)
                            RS.Columns[LECTOR.GetName(i)].DataType = typeof(string);
                        }
                        flag = !flag; // to mark that tthe column creation is done
                    }
                    //create a data row out of the scope
                    DataRow FILA = RS.NewRow();
                    for (int i = 0; i < LECTOR.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        //Put the data into the row, using the key (GetName)
                        FILA[LECTOR.GetName(i)] = LECTOR.GetValue(i).ToString();
                        //checks if it is the last case (I dont know why it didn't work if I wrote it after the for)
                        if (i + 1 == LECTOR.FieldCount) { RS.Rows.Add(FILA); }

                    }   
                }
```

And that's it this is the basis to do more complex things. After this I have to think if it is the best to do this at the class, or do it each time I do a query, for that I will have to see how often I will need to modify the data type.

Sorry about my poor english. And thank you guys who guide me to this.